Url rewrites to other domain in nextjs 14
I have two domain let say domain a.com and b.com now my goal is when user on website hit a.com/next should show the content of the b.com.
Now i am able to achieve this from the nextjs rewrites in nextjs.config file
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/next/:path*",
        destination: "https://b.com/:path*",
      },
    ];
  },
};

But the i am getting 404 error when domain a.com is fetching the resources of b.com. How to solve this issue

I tried to configure CSP as research about it and got this information this can be possibly blocking your site to get resources but i don't get any header in response regarding CSP
Look for CORS but unable to resolve

